# How to prevent overloading JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

i'm using jwt token with node.js npm `jsonwebtoken` in  order to manage my users authentication. above that i'm  adding to the payload the user permissions which contains the user read and write to which section.

like so:

```
const payload = {
  user: {
    id: user.id,
    permissions: user.account_permissions
  }
};

jwt.sign(
  payload,
  config.get('jwtSecret'),
  { expiresIn: TIME},
  (err, token) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json({ token });
  }
);
```

The `account_permissions` object looks somthing like that:

```
 const permissions = {
    platform: 'Management',
    sections: [
      {
        sectionName: 'setup',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'chat',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'maintenence',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'classes',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'income',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'announcements',
        read: true,
        write: true
      },
      {
        sectionName: 'messages',
        read: true,
        write: true
      }
    ],
    school: shoolID
  };
```

My question is ; every user can have many permissions objects to different platforms which in that case makes the jwt token to be very large (sometimes to big to be even sent in the header).
I have a middleware that checks the user permissions in every route, im trying to avoid saving that data in a database in order to save database calls. how can i avoid such an overloading.

Comment: interesting article: https://sdoxsee.github.io/blog/2020/01/06/stop-overloading-jwts-with-permission-claims.html

Comment: I have read this article before, the problem arises when in my case every user representing user X’s “identity". every X identity (or role) can have different permissions , let say you are a worker with the identity of "Store Manager" each Store Manager identity have different permission set.